# Show that map from set of bases to change of base matrices is bijective

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

Let $V$ be some finite-dimensional $K$-vector space and $A=\{v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_n\}$ be a base of $V$. By $\textrm{GL}_K(n)$ denote the set of invertible $(n\times n$)-matrices with entries in $K$.

Show that the map
$$
\phi\colon\{\textrm{Bases of }V\}\to \textrm{GL}_K(n),\quad B\longmapsto M_B^A(\textrm{id})
$$
is a bijection.

(Here $M_B^A(\textrm{id})$ denotes the change of basis matrix.)

---

First of all, if I do understand it correctly, $V=K^n$, so that each $v_j\in A$ is an $n$-vector with entries in $K$, that is, $v_j=(v_{1,j}, v_{2,j},\ldots v_{n,j})^\top\in K^n$.

**Surjectivity:**

Let
$$
M_B^A(\textrm{id})=\begin{pmatrix}a_{11} & \cdots & a_{1n}\\\vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
a_{n1} & \ldots & a_{nn}\end{pmatrix}\in \textrm{GL}_K(n)
$$
be given. I need to show there exists a base $B=\{w_1,\ldots,w_n\}$ of $V$ such that $\phi(B)= M_B^A(\textrm{id})$. But this base $B$ should simply be given by
$$
B=A\cdot(M_B^A(\textrm{id}))^{-1},
$$
where bases $A$ and $B$ are in fact matrices,
$$
A=\begin{pmatrix}v_{1,1} & \ldots & v_{1,n}\\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
v_{n,1} & \ldots & v_{n,n}\end{pmatrix},\qquad B=\begin{pmatrix}w_{1,1} & \ldots & w_{1,n}\\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
w_{n,1} & \ldots & w_{n,n}\end{pmatrix}.
$$

**Injectivity:**

Suppose $\phi(B)=M_B^A(\textrm{id})=M_C^A(\textrm{id})=\phi(C)$. I need to deduce that $B=C$.

If we write again
$$
M_B^A(\textrm{id})=\begin{pmatrix}a_{11} & \cdots & a_{1n}\\\vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\a_{n1} & \cdots & a_{nn}\end{pmatrix},
$$
$A=\{v_1,\ldots,v_n\}$, and $B=\{w_1,\ldots,w_n\}$ as well as $C=\{z_1,\ldots,z_n\}$, again, strictly speaking, all matrices
$$
A=\begin{pmatrix}v_{1,1} & \ldots & v_{1,n}\\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
v_{n,1} & \ldots & v_{n,n}\end{pmatrix}, \qquad B=\begin{pmatrix}w_{1,1} & \ldots & w_{1,n}\\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
w_{n,1} & \ldots & w_{n,n}\end{pmatrix}, \qquad C=\begin{pmatrix}z_{1,1} & \ldots & z_{1,n}\\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
z_{n,1} & \ldots & z_{n,n}\end{pmatrix},
$$

we shall have
$$
A=B\cdot M_B^A(\textrm{id}) = C\cdot M_C^A(\textrm{id})=C\cdot M_B^A(\textrm{id})
$$

and thus,
$$
A\cdot (M_B^A(\textrm{id}))^{-1}=B=C.
$$
Thus, $B=C$.

I am not sure if my prove is correct. Seems to be too easy if you ask me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume $\def\id{\operatorname{id}}M^A_B(\id)$ stands for the change of basis matrix from (the fixed basis) $A$ to (the variable basis) $B$, meaning that its columns give the coordinates with respect to $A$ of the basis$~B$.

To me, working such problems out in terms of matrix operations is rather confusing, since it is really about linear maps, in particular about isomorphisms between vector spaces. So I'll think of a matrix in $\def\GL{\mathbf{GL}}\GL_K(n)$ as an isomorphism of the particular vector space $K^n$ (the operation of left-multiplying by the matrix). Any basis $B$ of the separate vector space $V$ gives rise to an isomorphism $\gamma_B:K^n\to{V}$ that map the elements of the standard basis of $K^n$ in order to the elements of $B$; it is an instance of the more general map $K^d\to{V}$ defined by a $d$-tuple of vectors in$~V$ by mapping any $(c_1,\ldots,c_d)\in{K^d}$ to the linear combination of those vectors with the $c_i$ as coefficients, and $B$ is a basis means precisely that $\gamma_B$ is an isomorphism. The inverse $\gamma_B^{-1}:V\to{K^n}$ is then well defined, and it is the coordinate map for$~B$. By the above description, the change of basis matrix $M^A_B(\id)$ is (the matrix of) the composition $\gamma_A^{-1}\circ\gamma_B$ (simply check what the composition does to a standard basis vector).

Now the statement to check becomes quite obvious. The map $f:B\to{\gamma_A^{-1}\circ\gamma_B}$ is injective because no two bases give the same map $\gamma_B$: $f(B)=f(B')$ implies $\gamma_B=\gamma_{B'}$, and since each vector of$~B$ is the image by $\gamma_B$ of a specific standard basis vector, this implies $B=B'$. To see that $f$ is surjective, fix an isomorphism $\psi$ of $K^n$; the condition $f(B)=\psi$ means $\gamma_A^{-1}\circ\gamma_B=\psi$ or $\gamma_B=\gamma_A\circ\psi$, so a basis $B$ can be found by applying the isomorphism $\gamma_A\circ\psi:{K^n}\to{V}$ to the standard basis vectors.

In fact this an instance of a more general correspondence that does not involve bases at all. If you have (in some category) two structures $X$ and $Y$ that are isomorphic (but presumably not canonically so), then fixing one isomorphism $a:X\to{Y}$ determines a bijection between the set of all such isomorphisms $b:X\to{Y}$ and the group of automorphisms $\psi:X\to{X}$ by the correspondence $b\mapsto{a^{-1}}\circ{b}$. The bijectivity is immediate from the fact that $\psi\mapsto{a}\circ\psi$ is its inverse.

Comment: This made things very clear to me, wonderful! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

To be clear, do you mean that $M_B^A(\mathrm{id})$ denotes the change of basis matrix from the base $B$ to the base $A$ or from $A$ to $B$ ? Usually the change of basis matrix from $B$ to $A$ is noted $M_B^A$ (or $P_B^A$) without the $\mathrm{id}$ and you would note $M_{A, B}(\mathrm{id}) = M_B^A$ when you really want to see the change of basis as the matrix of a linear map (which is much clearer from my point of view).

If this is indeed the change of basis from $B$ to $A$, then the relations should be $B = M_B^A \cdot A$. To be sure of this fact instead of directly writing basis as matrix(which is not entirerly correct, but it is the idea behind this bijection) you can write $M_{A, B}(\mathrm{id})\cdot M_{B_0, A}(\mathrm{id}) = M_{B_0, B}(\mathrm{id})$ (where $B_0$ is the canonical base of $K^n$) and this relation is much easier to read : you start from the basis $B_0$, go to the basis $A$, then to the basis $B$ which is exactly the same as going from $B_0$ to $B$.

However, as you can see it is quite tidious to work with to many change of basis matrix and I might have done some mistakes although I checked multiple times. To avoid this, you can at first reduce the problem by proving that you have a bijection

$$ \varphi : \lbrace \text{basis of } K^n \rbrace \to \mathrm{GL}_n(K), \ B \mapsto M_B^{B_0}$$

This bijection is not hard to prove and you kind of assumed it all along your proof : it consists just of stating that $M_B^{B_0}$ is the matrix which columns are the vectors of the base $B$ written in the canonical base. For a base $B = (v_1, \ldots, v_n)$, you have $M_B^{B_0} = (v_1^{\bot} \mid \cdots \mid v_n^{\bot})$.
You already reduced the problem by assuming that $V = K^n$, which is equivalent to changing the base you are working with. To get the general result over $K^n$ for an arbitrary basis $A$, you can notice that $M_B^A = M_B^{B_0}\cdot M_{B_0}^A$. And to get the even more general result over a vector space $V$ of dimension $n$, you can use well-known bijections between $V$ and $K^n$. But really, the heart of the result is the bijection $\varphi$ mentionned earlier, the rest is just to tidious for what it actually says.

But you had all the right ingredients, if you change the relations "$B = A\cdot(M_A^B(\mathrm{id}))^{-1}$" to $B = M_B^A \cdot A$, your proof is correct (given that you prove the bijection $\varphi$ that I introduced).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. In the exercise it is said "from $A$ to $B$".

Comment: In that case, you can take the inverse matrix, since $(M_A^B)^{-1} = M_B^A$.